# setVolumeControlStream not working when a popup window is displayed

Tags: java, android

I have `this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);` at the start of all activities in my application so when the user presses the volume up or down buttons, he controls the media volume.

I have a popup window in my program and when that appears the user can no longer control the volume.

Looking at similar questions it seems that setting up `onKeyup/down` listeners can interfere with the process - but I have not set any up - the only listeners I have for the popup window are `setOnClickListeners` for the buttons and a `setOnDismissListener` for the window.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been creating the popup window with

```
my_popup_window = new PopupWindow(layout, x, y,  true);
```

I then change it to this...

```
my_popup_window = new PopupWindow(layout);
my_popup_window.setWidth(x);
my_popup_window.setHeight(y);
```

and the volume control started to work again. I don't understand why - but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to call [setOwnerActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOwnerActivity%28android.app.Activity%29) on the `Dialog` object.

Documentation from the method:

> Sets the Activity that owns this dialog. An example use: This Dialog will use the suggested volume control stream of the Activity.

While not tested, this should do the trick. There is also the possibility to use [setVolumeControlStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setVolumeControlStream%28int%29).

Comment: Sadly I have a PopupWindow, not a Dialog, and neither setOwnerActivity nor setVolumeControlStream appear to be available.

Comment: Then you are out of luck, I lurked through the AOSP source of `PopupWindow.java` and `Dialog.java` to the how it could be done but it just can't. The `PopupWindow` makes use of the private API of the `WindowManager` to display the view. You would need to call 'setVolumeControlStream()' on the `Window` but it's simply not used. Is there any chance you can change to a `Dialog` based window?

Comment: I'll look into it - but I am not confident because this is the most complicated window I have ever made. Its highly customised, contains animations and is created entirely programatically.

Comment: Couldn't you just put your `View` into the `Dialog` and customize the `Dialog` look and feel until it matches your old implementation? It shoudn't be that much work as a `Dialog` allows you to just 'stick in' a custom view.

Comment: I'll give that a go if nothing turns up on SO, but I find it hard to believe its the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just do this `pop.setFocusable(false)`. and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

though the Mick's answer didn't work for me, this is for posterity.

```
//Declaration
PopupWindow mWindow;
...

//Constructor
mWindow     = new PopupWindow(context);
...

//Prepare to Show
mWindow.setContentView();
mWindow.setBackgroundDrawable();
mWindow.setFocusable(false);
...
```

setting ***setFocusable*** to **false** helped my activity capture `onKeyDown()` again.